# AAAI review criteria

Tags: conference, computer-science, paper-submission

I am submitting my first paper ever to AAAI and I really would like it to be accepted, but I feel like it is not good enough.

Can anyone tell me the criteria they use so I can tweak my paper to better fit them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to determine their criteria is to look at what has previously been accepted in your area of research. AAAI is generally a strong conference with tight standards (around 15% last I recall, if I'm remembering correctly), so there will also be a significant stochastic component driven by the particular reviewers you draw and their mood when they read your paper. AAAI has been taking steps to make the process more fair, however, including giving an author response period, so you are likely to be treated reasonably given the quality of your work.

Bottom line: compare your work to similar prior, and if its close, submit. And be prepared to learn from the experience.